# SQLite database not getting copied (No such a table exists error)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I think my database is not getting copied cause my **database file in the assets folder is 32KB** and the **file that shows up in the device file explorer is 12KB**. So I tried uploading database file from device file explorer then there was no errors. Please can somebody help me fix this?

[image: database in device file explorer]

This is the error I'm getting

[image: error]

This is my DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

    DatabaseHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    List<Contacts> contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Station> stationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Tip> tipsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public List<Contacts> getAllContacts() {
        String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME, DatabaseHelper.KEY_POSITION, DatabaseHelper.KEY_STATION, DatabaseHelper.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, DatabaseHelper.KEY_EMAIL};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME1, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME);
            String name = cursor.getString(index2);
            int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_POSITION);
            String position = cursor.getString(index3);
            int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STATION);
            String station = cursor.getString(index4);
            int index5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER);
            String phone_number = cursor.getString(index5);
            int index6 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_EMAIL);
            String email = cursor.getString(index6);

            Contacts contact = new Contacts(name, position, station, phone_number, email);
            contactsList.add(contact);
        }
        return contactsList;
    }

    public List<Station> getAllStations() {
        String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_NAME, DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_ADDRESS, DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_PHONE_NUMBER, DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_TOTAL_FIGHTERS, DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_TOTAL_VEHICLES, DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_LAT, DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_LON};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_NAME);
            String name = cursor.getString(index1);
            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_ADDRESS);
            String address = cursor.getString(index2);
            int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_PHONE_NUMBER);
            String phone_number = cursor.getString(index3);
            int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_TOTAL_FIGHTERS);
            int total_f = cursor.getInt(index4);
            int index5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_TOTAL_VEHICLES);
            int total_v = cursor.getInt(index5);
            int index6 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_LAT);
            String lat = cursor.getString(index6);
            int index7 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_S_LON);
            String lon = cursor.getString(index7);

            Station station = new Station(name, address, phone_number, total_f, total_v, lat, lon);
            stationsList.add(station);
        }
        return stationsList;
    }

    public List<Tip> getAllTips() {
        String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.KEY_TIP_TOPIC, DatabaseHelper.KEY_TIP_SUB_TOPIC};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME3, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TIP_TOPIC);
            String topic = cursor.getString(index2);
            int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TIP_SUB_TOPIC);
            String sub_topic = cursor.getString(index3);

            Tip tip = new Tip(topic, sub_topic);
            tipsList.add(tip);
        }
        return tipsList;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Firefighters.db";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "contact_list";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "station_list";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME3 = "tips";

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";
        private static final String KEY_STATION = "station";
        private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
        private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

        private static final String KEY_S_NAME = "name";
        private static final String KEY_S_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String KEY_S_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
        private static final String KEY_S_TOTAL_FIGHTERS = "total_fighters";
        private static final String KEY_S_TOTAL_VEHICLES = "total_vehicles";
        private static final String KEY_S_LAT = "lat";
        private static final String KEY_S_LON = "long";

        private static final String KEY_TIP_TOPIC = "tip_topic";
        private static final String KEY_TIP_SUB_TOPIC = "tip_sub_topic";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my database copy class

```
public class PreCreateDB {

    public static void copyDB(Context context){
        try{
            String destPath = "/data/data/"+ context.getPackageName()
                    + "/databases";
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if(!f.exists()){
                f.mkdir();
                rawCopy(context.getAssets().open("Firefighters.db"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/Firefighters.db"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rawCopy(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

And this is how I call them

```
        PreCreateDB.copyDB(mContext);
        databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(mContext);
        stationsList = databaseAdapter.getAllStations();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        stationsAdapter = new StationsAdapter(mContext, stationsList, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(stationsAdapter);
```

### **-- Solution that worked for me --**

I tried everything and none of them seem to work so then I tried this [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library and it worked! All I did was extend Database helper with SQLiteAssetHelper. This is my Database helper now.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Firefighters.db";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "contact_list";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "station_list";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME3 = "tips";

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";
        private static final String KEY_STATION = "station";
        private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
        private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

        private static final String KEY_S_NAME = "name";
        private static final String KEY_S_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String KEY_S_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";
        private static final String KEY_S_TOTAL_FIGHTERS = "total_fighters";
        private static final String KEY_S_TOTAL_VEHICLES = "total_vehicles";
        private static final String KEY_S_LAT = "lat";
        private static final String KEY_S_LON = "long";

        private static final String KEY_TIP_TOPIC = "tip_topic";
        private static final String KEY_TIP_SUB_TOPIC = "tip_sub_topic";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happpens if you add `outputStream.flush();` before the close ? Are you sure the tables names match in the database match the table names? I would suggest efore `stationsList = databaseAdapter.getAllStations();` running a query based upon SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;  and using the **DatabaseUtils dumpCursor** method to check what components make up the copied database. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor(android.database.Cursor,%20java.io.PrintStream)

Comment: Yes I didn't find any table name mismatches and when I upload the database from device file explorer it's working perfectly like all data is getting read and displayed but I'll try adding outputStream.flush();

Comment: Found the issue, the database folder/directory exists so no copy is attempted and new empty (without your tables) is created. Hence table not found. Corrected the answer with a suggested PreCreateDB.copyDB method, but left the other answers in as they could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Correction**

Your issue is that you have other databases/files (thanks to google stuff). So the **database folder already exists** and therefore **it won't copy the file** but instead it will open a **new database** with just the android_metadata table.

Try using :-

```
public static void copyDB(Context context){
    String destPath = context.getDatabasePath("FireFighters.db").getAbsolutePath();
    File f = new File(destPath);
    if(!f.exists()){
        if(!f.getParentFile().exists()) {
            f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            rawCopy(context.getAssets().open("Firefighters.db"), new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/Firefighters.db"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

So this checks to see if the database file (*Firefighters.db*) itself exists. If not then it will:-

1. create the database directory if it doesn't exists
2. irrespective of the databases directory existing then copy the *Firefighters.db*.

If *Firefighters.db* file exists then the file is not copied.

**Previous Answer** (probably not applicable)

I would suspect that what has been copied is not what you expect it to be. The 12KB along with message (table not found) indicates 2 things. A valid database exists and that it likely has a few components. i.e. (tables,views,indexes,triggers) (each would take up at least 4KB (1 page))

First thing to try is uninstalling the App and rerunning to eliminate an existing attempt leaving a valid but empty component wise (tables etc) database.

It that doesn't resolve the issue then I would suggest adding the following

```
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(databaseAdapter.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master",null));
```

before the line `stationsList = databaseAdapter.getAllStations();`

This will extract a list of all the components (tables, views triggers, indexes) in the database e.g. something like :-

```
2022-01-23 13:01:13.611 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@45ef147
2022-01-23 13:01:13.611 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out: }
2022-01-23 13:01:13.612 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

i.e. the above has only the android_metadata table which the SQLiteOpenHelper creates.

Note the above was created using your helper without PreCreateDB,copyDB being called. And low and behold device Explorer shows:-

[image]

As such it doesn't look like the PreCreateDB.copyDB is copying the file OR if it is that perhaps it's corrupted in which case SQLiteOpenHelper will prsent you a brand spanking new but empty database bar the android_metadata table.

**Additional**

Doing a quick test of your code but with a database that contains other tables (for my convenience rather than create one after studying your code) and using outStream().flush.

Then using :-

```
    PreCreateDB.copyDB(this);
    databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(databaseAdapter.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master",null));
```

results in :-

```
2022-01-23 13:25:25.439 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@dda8d74
2022-01-23 13:25:25.440 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-01-23 13:25:25.440 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-01-23 13:25:25.440 I/System.out:    name=kmmAccounts
2022-01-23 13:25:25.440 I/System.out:    tbl_name=kmmAccounts
2022-01-23 13:25:25.440 I/System.out:    rootpage=2
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE kmmAccounts (id varchar(32) NOT NULL, institutionId varchar(32), parentId varchar(32), lastReconciled timestamp, lastModified timestamp, openingDate date, accountNumber mediumtext, accountType varchar(16) NOT NULL, accountTypeString mediumtext, isStockAccount char(1), accountName mediumtext, description mediumtext, currencyId varchar(32), balance mediumtext, balanceFormatted mediumtext, transactionCount bigint unsigned, PRIMARY KEY (id))
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out: }
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    type=index
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_autoindex_kmmAccounts_1
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    tbl_name=kmmAccounts
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    sql=null
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out: }
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out: 2 {
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    name=kmmAccountsPayeeIdentifier
2022-01-23 13:25:25.441 I/System.out:    tbl_name=kmmAccountsPayeeIdentifier
2022-01-23 13:25:25.442 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2022-01-23 13:25:25.442 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE kmmAccountsPayeeIdentifier (accountId varchar(32) NOT NULL, userorder smallint unsigned NOT NULL, identifierId varchar(32) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (accountId, userorder))
2022-01-23 13:25:25.442 I/System.out: }
....
```

Device explorer shows :-

[image]

So your code, with the flush added, works. So it's either excluding the flush or the asset file that is at fault and I would guess that the asset file is either not  the correct file name, empty component wise or is corrupt.

**Corrupt File**

If it is corrupt the log should show as such e.g. (an image copied into asset as Firfighters.db) :-

```
2022-01-23 13:37:07.973 E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is not a database
2022-01-23 13:37:07.974 E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/user/0/a.a.so70599236javasqlitenorows/databases/Firefighters.db
2022-01-23 13:37:07.974 E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: deleting the database file: /data/user/0/a.a.so70599236javasqlitenorows/databases/Firefighters.db
2022-01-23 13:37:08.013 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@dda8d74
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out: }
2022-01-23 13:37:08.014 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

**Incorrect Named Asset File**

renaming the asset to anything other than Firefighters.db (e.g. NotFirefighters.db) results in the log including:-

```
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Firefighters.db
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:744)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:721)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at a.a.so70599236javasqlitenorows.PreCreateDB.copyDB(PreCreateDB.java:20)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at a.a.so70599236javasqlitenorows.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.204 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.205 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.206 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.233 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@dda8d74
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out: }
2022-01-23 13:43:18.234 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

**So by adding the sqlite extract and cursor dump, running after uninstalling the App and viewing the log should establish the cause.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I tried everything you said but the app just kept getting crashed then I found out about the SQLiteAssetHelper library then after extending it the app works perfectly now!